# Atualizar campo de tabela sem refresh?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tenho uma "div" que trás o dado de uma tabela "Mysql", como eu faço para que ao clicar nessa "div" o dado torna-se editável ? Mas sem ir para outra página.

```html
<div id="nome_mysql">João</div>
```

Ao clicar em João, a "div" se tornaria um "input text", onde eu pudesse trocar o nome por outro, e após ter feito a troca, o "input text" retornaria a ser uma "div" normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando dizes *"ao clicar nessa div o dado torna-se editável"* o melhor é teres um `input` escondido que aparece quando clicas na div. Assim o valor que editares fica sempre na página, mesmo que o `input` esteja escondido.

Exemplo:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('nome_mysql');
var input = document.querySelector('input[nome="nome_mysql"]');
console.log(div, input)

function toggleElements(show, hide) {
    show.style.display = 'block';
    hide.style.display = 'none';
    show.focus();
}

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = this.innerText;
    toggleElements(input, this);
});
input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    div.innerText = this.value;
    toggleElements(div, this);
});
```

```css
input[nome="nome_mysql"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nome_mysql">João</div>
<input type="text" nome="nome_mysql" />
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwy4zyrb/1/

Comment: é exatamente o que preciso, que um dia eu possa recompensar  esforço de pessoas como vc... Após a edição esse dado pode ser enviado ao banco? grato, grato e grato